# How to display a badge when a chat thread has unread messages React JS, Firestore

Tags: reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, use-effect, use-state

I am developing a chat application in React and firebase firestore. I want to display an unread messages badge every time a new message is added to the database. Currently, I am using a useEffect hook to check if the last message is read, and that only works only the first time the page renders - the unread messages badge appears only after I reload the page. I think what I can't figure out is how to re-render every time the state changes. Kindly look at my code and tell me what I am missing. I hope my issue is clear. Thanks in advance.

```
const [chatMessages, setChatMessages] = useState([])
const [isRead, setIsRead] = useState(false)

const readsRef = db.collection('rooms').doc(id).collection('messages')

useEffect(() => {

    const unsubscribe = readsRef.orderBy('timestamp', 'desc')

        .limit(1).onSnapshot((snapshot) => {
            snapshot.docs.map((snap) => {
                setChatMessages(snap.data().message)

                 readsRef.doc(snap.id).collection('read').doc(userID.uid).onSnapshot((snapshot1 => {
                    if (snapshot1.get('readReceipt') === userID.uid) {
                        setIsRead(true)
   
                    }
            
                }))

            })

    })
    return unsubscribe;
    
}, [isRead])


 return (

 <SidebarOptionChannel>

                   
    <span># </span>{title} - {chatMessages}<span>{isRead ? null : <UnreadBadge> 
    <span>1</span></UnreadBadge>  }</span>

  </SidebarOptionChannel>
 )
```

Comment: what is readReports?

Comment: Looks like code is incomplete, `isRead` is added as dependency for useEffects but I don't see any state variable `isRead`. Update the question with proper details, code sandbox link would be better

Comment: Sorry! I have edited it to include the variables. Please check again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution to your problem could be to update your chat application by  listening for changes in your Database of Firebase. This can be done by using the methods of firebase.database.Reference:

> on() or once()

Here is an example provided by the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/read-and-write#read_data) of Firebase:

```js
var starCountRef = firebase.database().ref('posts/' + postId + '/starCount');
starCountRef.on('value', (snapshot) => {
  const data = snapshot.val();
  updateStarCount(postElement, data);
});
```

Comment: please check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75220565/how-to-do-when-msg-is-readed-then-color-is-change-or-msg-is-nor-read-its-color